# How to reduce extra white space on a web page

Tags: html, css

In this image, on left side there is half side view of website and on the right side there is extra space which I want to omit. Also look at the bottom there is a bar which I don't want.

How do I remove this extra space?

[image]

css

```
/* CSS Document */
body{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
background-image: url(../images/tile.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
img{
border:0px;
}
.flt{
float:left;
}
#wh_bg{
width:1000px;
margin:auto;
}
#bg_bg{
width:1000px;
float:left;
margin-left: -40px;
margin-top: -50px;
}
/*top panel starts here*/

.logo{
float:left;
margin:89px 0px 0px -15px;
position:relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#menu{
width:1000px;
float:left;
height:56px;

}
.men_tp{
width:900px;
float:left;
display:inline;
padding:24px 0px 0px 70px;
}
.men_tp a{
float:left;
color:#686666;
font:bold 12px/15px tahoma;
text-decoration:none;
margin-left:25px;
}
/*top panel ends here*/
/*content panel starts here*/
#content{
width:1000px;
float:left;
}

.img_txt{
float:left;
position:relative;
margin:-10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
.img_tp{
width:865px;
float:left;
background:url(../images/img_tp.gif) no-repeat;
height:15px;
}
#con{
width:865px;
float:left;
background:url(../images/part_bg.gif) repeat-y;
}
.con1{
width:560px;
float:left;
display:inline;
padding-left:4px;
padding-top:10px;

}
.con2{
width:280px;
float:left;
padding-left:20px;
display:inline;
padding-top:10px;
}
.txt{
width:560px;
float:left;
margin-top:35px;
color:#515455;
font:12px/18px georgia;
}
.wor{
float:right;
position:relative;
margin:-30px 10px 0px 0px;
}
#part2{
width:1000px;
float:left;
}
#cen{
width:640px;
float:left;
height:237px;
background:#009BD9;
}

.cont{
float:left;
margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.con_txt{
width:211px;
color:#515455;
float:left;
font:12px/16px georgia;
margin:10px 0px 0px 20px;
}
.abt_txt{
width:550px;
float:left;
margin-top:15px;
color:#FFF;
font:12px/18px georgia;
}
#link{
width:257px;
float:left;
padding:10px 0px 0px 15px;
}


.copy{
width:700px;
float:left;
margin:10px 0px 0px 200px;
color:#D4D0D0;
font:12px/18px georgia;
}

.copy a{ color:#D4D0D0; font:12px/18px georgia; }
/*footer panel ends here*/

.contecnt1
{
    width:400px;
    height:480px;
    margin-top: 100px;
 padding-top  : 60px;
 font-family:Candara;
 font-variant:normal;


}

.imgg
{
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-top:-40px;

}
.imggss
{
    margin-left:40px;

    margin-top: -100px;
}
.para
{
    text-align:justify;
    color:Black;
    float:left;
    width:990px;
    padding-left:20px;
}
 .img_wrper
 {
 background-image:url("images/Malaysian-Flag.png");
 width  :990px;
    height:492px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-top:150px;
 }







.contPers
{

margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 230px;

    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-left:65px;
    }  
    .contPers1
{
    width: 990px;
height: 800px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 230px;
    background-color:#E6E6FA;
    padding-right: 10px;

    }  


        .contPers2
{
    width: 990px;
height: 1100;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 210px;
    background-color:#E6E6FA;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-left:70px;   

    }  

.pers
{
    font-family:Candara;
    font-size:18px;
    padding-left:18px;
    padding-top:30px;
    font-weight:normal;

}
.persjbssr
{
    font-family: Candara;
font-size: 18px;
padding-left: 18px;
padding-top: 30px;
font-weight: normal;
}   
.pes1
{
            font-family:Candara;
    font-size:20px;
    padding-left:18px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin-left: -70px;
}              
.para1
{
     padding-left:18px;
     font-size:15px;
     font-weight:normal;
        font-family:Candara;
        text-align:justify;
       margin-left:-70px;
       width:1000px;

}

.imggs
{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:40px;

    width:100px;
}

.imggs1
{
    margin-left:20px;
    width:100px;
    height:120px
}
.imggs2
{
    margin-left:20px;
    width:150px;

}
```

html of index file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="js/MyMenu1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />


<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function Text_Newsletter_onclick() {

}

// -->
</script>





    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>





</head>
<body>
<div id="headerrrr">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">+603 2201 1665</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="wh_bg">
<div id="bg_bg">
<div><a href="#"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="" width="320" height="60" /></a></div>
<div class="social">
<ul>
<li>Connect US :</li>
<li><a href=""><img src="images/fb.jpg" alt="facebook" /></a></li>
<li><a><img src="images/linkde.jpg" alt="facebook" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="menu">
<div id="wrap">
<ul class="navbar">
<li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
<ul id="Ul1">
<li><a id="A1" href="">abc</a></li>
<li><a href="">def</a></li>
<li><a href="l">xyz</a></li>
<li><a href="">aaa</a></li>
<li><a href="">bbb</a></li>
<li><a href="">ccc</a></li>
<li><a href="">ddd/li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">eee</a>
<ul id="Ul2">
<li><a id="A2" href="">fff</a></li>
<li><a href="">ggg/a></li>
<li><a href="">hhh</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">iii </a></li>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
<li><a href="">ghj</a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a>
<ul id="subnavlist">
<li class="b"><a id="subcurrent" href="#"></a>
<ul class="c">
<li class="a"><a href="">A</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="Data_collec_services.htm">Data Collection Services</a></li>
<li><a href="Proof_Edit.html">Editing &amp; Proof Reading</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="active"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div align="center"><img class="imaeslidr" src="images/Slider Animation/Slider2.gif" alt="" width="1050" height="375" /></div>
<div class="blankSeparator">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="indxim" style="background-image: url(''); width: 1050px; height: 800px;">
<div class="contecntA ">
<div class="indpara">
<h2 class="hindx">About US</h2>
<p class="paraindex">Read More</a></p>
<h2 class="hindx"></h2>
<p class="paraindex"></p>
<h2 class="hindx">Research</h2>
<p class="paraindex"></p>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
<h2 class="indxparaz">HOT LINKS</h2>
<ul class="sidebar">
<li><a href="Upcomngevents.html">Up Coming Events</a></li>
<li><a href="Member_ship.html">Membership</a></li>
<li><a href="Registration.html">Registration</a></li>
<li><a href="Personnel.html">Our Personnel</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
<br /><br />
<h2 class="indxparaz2">Our Personnel</h2>
<span class="con_txtslider"> <img src="images/personeslider.gif" alt="" /> </span></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="blankSeparator">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="footer22">
<h2 class="footerhead">Newsletter</h2>
<hr /><input id="Text1" class="footertxt" type="text" /><br /> <input id="Submit1" class="footerbutton" type="submit" value="submit" />
<div>
<h2 class="footerhead1">UpComing Events</h2>
<div class="foopara2"><a class="eventss" href="Upcomngevents.html">Events Available</a></div>
</div>
<h2 class="footerhead2">Contact Us</h2>
<div class="foopara">Call now to find out how: +603 2201 1665 <br /><br /> <a class="email" href="https://secure.ipage.com/secure/login.bml" target="_blank"> <img src="images/email-login.png" alt="signin" /> </a></div>
<br /><br /><br /><hr />
<div class="ffpara">
<p class="ffpara">&copy; Copyright 2014, </p>
</div>
<div class="ffpara2">
<p class="ffpara2">T:  E:</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK down voters and close voters, just because the question was all upper case, no need to punish the asker. Now we fixed that, can someone help CapricornGurl?

Comment: Not sure what browser you have the issue on. It is pretty centered in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/nn01Lxwr/

Comment: looking at your css, you are using unnecessary margins for everything. also <br> tags which can be deal with other css properties

Comment: Your whole code can be greatly improved. You might want to check the following articles to improve your css skills (too many code you don't need especially that margins) and start from scratch again: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started & http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design.

Comment: Next time you might want to remove all the irrelevant code, and you might want to look at all the margins you have in your css.

Answer (score 0):

ok i notice it where is mistake in menu bar when i remove width=140% it is fine and extra space is gone but when i add width=140% it occur extra space and also menu look like this see this link

[image](http://oi57.tinypic.com/e6yc90.jpg)

menu bar code

```
.wrap   {
    width: 100%; /* Spans the width of the page */
    height: 40px; 
    margin: 0; /* Ensures there is no space between sides of the screen and the menu */
    z-index: 99; /* Makes sure that your menu remains on top of other page elements */
    position: relative; 
    background-color: #366b82;
    }

    .navbar {
      height: 50px;
        border-right: 1px solid #54879d;

        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position:absolute;
        margin-left:40px;


  }

    .navbar li  {
            height: auto;
            width: 131px;  /* Each menu item is 150px wide */
            float: left;  /* This lines up the menu items horizontally */
            text-align: center;  /* All text is placed in the center of the box */
            list-style: none;  /* Removes the default styling (bullets) for the list */
            font: normal bold 12px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;  
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #366b82;
                        }


                        .navbar a   {                           
        padding: 18px 0;  /* Adds a padding on the top and bottom so the text appears centered vertically */
        border-left: 1px solid #54879d; /* Creates a border in a slightly lighter shade of blue than the background.  Combined with the right border, this creates a nice effect. */
        border-right: 1px solid #1f5065; /* Creates a border in a slightly darker shade of blue than the background.  Combined with the left border, this creates a nice effect. */
        text-decoration: none;  /* Removes the default hyperlink styling. */
        color: white; /* Text color is white */
        display: block;
        }

        .navbar li:hover, a:hover {background-color: #54879d;} 


        .navbar li ul   {
        display: none;  /* Hides the drop-down menu */
        height: auto;                                   
        margin: 0; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */
        padding: 0; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */         
        }               

.navbar li:hover ul     {
                        display: block; /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */
                        }

                        .navbar li ul li {background-color: #54879d;} 


                        .navbar li ul li a  {
        border-left: 1px solid #1f5065; 
        border-right: 1px solid #1f5065; 
        border-top: 1px solid #74a3b7; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid #1f5065; 
        }

.navbar li ul li a:hover    {background-color: #366b82;}

.navbar li ul li ul li {
      margin-top:-50px;
      margin-left:130px;
      display:block;
  }
```